# How to run Ruby scripts in Command Line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I've installed Jekyll and I'm trying to import a simple CSV file with a few posts. I've never used Ruby before. In Jekyll's import docs it shows the following code that needs to be run via Command Line.

http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/csv/

```
$ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import";
JekyllImport::Importers::CSV.run({
  "file" => "my_posts.csv"
})'
```

I'm I supposed to type the whole thing into Command Line and run it or is the first line supposed to call a function that includes the last three lines of code?

Sorry for the noob question but I really couldn't find any answers to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put scripts in a file with a `.rb` extension and run it with:

```
ruby import_csv.rb
```

Your file `import_csv.rb` would contain:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "jekyll-import";
JekyllImport::Importers::CSV.run({
  "file" => "my_posts.csv"
})
```

I think the `-rubygems` switch is not needed since it is enabled by default. If not, add the line `require rubygems` before the other require line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm now trying to install the gem 'jekyll-import' with `gem install jekyll-import` but it's taking forever and no response from CLI. Is this normal that there's no reaction at all?

Comment: The `gem install` can be slow sometimes, but should not take minutes. Try running the same command again until it does something useful.

Comment: I'm running on OS Mavericks but from the docs it seems Ruby is already installed. I haven't installed anything else such as Macports or Homebrew. Do you think I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with setting up Ruby on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your codes in a file with rb extension, it should be something like this,

```
require 'rubygems'
require "jekyll-import"
JekyllImport::Importers::CSV.run({
  "file" => "my_posts.csv"
})
```

Lets say file name sample.rb. Then run this file using the following command,

```
ruby sample.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IRB console by typing `irb` at command prompt

Comment: So does this mean I type each line one after the other into command line and then press enter to execute the script?

Comment: Yes, it does. IRB is a really handle tool for quick stuff like this.